# iphone sinin and sinup code

Tags: iphone

i want the solution of below question, i dont know how to store sinup information in Plist, can any one knows please help.

Thanks in advance

Use  Dummy  data  but  the  dummy  data  must  not  be  in  the  code  ,it  should  either   be   in   an   external   file   (plist/xml)   or   in   a   separate   constant   file.This   improves   the   code  management.

> All  screens  must  comply  to  Portrait  and  Landscape  View  Mode     
>   1.   The   App   will   begin   with   the   Login   Screen,   The   screen   should   be   having   same   functionality  as  any  website.  
>         a.  Login  
>         b.  Sign  Up  
>         c.  Maximum  Tries  (3)  then  lock  the  app  
>         d.   Requires   Answer   to   secret   question   to   unlock   which   will   be   accepted   in   sign   up

Comment: Please stop asking similar questions like this over and over again. If you want a solution, you jolly well ask properly, not paste some homework-like question (I bet it's homework) and say "i want the solution".

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for storing small data like user credentials look for [NSUserDefault.](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults)

For automatic login, if the user has logged in previously look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603593/how-to-properly-work-retrieve-values-with-nsuserdefaults).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new .plist file to store the information.

Add New File in your project, of type "Property list". Its under the "Resource tab", on "Mac OS X" in the left pane of your xcode.

Once created, Now add new items in to it. The "Key" will be used the retrieve the value through the coding.

To retrieve the values in the coding, from .plist file, you can use this code:

```
 NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSDictionary* defaultSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR_PLIST_FILE_NAME.plist" ofType:nil]];
[defaults registerDefaults:defaultSettings];

NSString *sName = [defaultSettings objectForKey:@"Name"]; //the Name is the Key in .plist file, so its corresponding value will be fetched and store in sName variable
NSString *defaultDomain = [defaultSettings objectForKey:@"domain"];
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: ok thanks for your information, but i dint understand where to put this code,can you elaborate your answer and what i have code that code to past it below.

Comment: You can add this code, where ever you want to retrieve the information saved in your .plist file. Suppose you want the data from .plist file in ClassAViewController, then use this in its `-(void)viewDidLoad` or any other appropriate method.   (NOTE: You might have to change the keys in your .plist file. This is just a sample(